# How to use my own keyboard instead of the default?

Tags: android

I've created my own keyboard based on the sample keyboard provided by Google for an application that I've created. How can I use this keyboard in my application instead of the default keyboard for `EditText` input? I need to be able to hide the default keyboard and use mine instead.

Comment: In Manifest file for that activity U have to declare the tag for hide softkeyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that extends EditText and override the onCheckIsTextEditor():

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText 
{
  public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
      super(context, attrs);     
  }      
  @Override      
  public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() 
  {
      // Your code to use your own input method here.      
  }
}
```